# Python - How to use py.path.LocalPath.sysexec()

Tags: python

I'm trying to use `LocalPath.sysexec()` from the [py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py/) library, but [the documentation](http://pylib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/path.html#py._path.local.LocalPath.sysexec) is not clear enough for me to understand how to invoke it with the right syntax.

Here is some fake code that mimics my syntax:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Testing pylib implementation of subprocess.Popen

from py.path import local
import sys

path = local(sys.argv[1])

path.sysexec("/usr/bin/foo", ["arg1", "arg2"])
```

Comment: Just curious, what's the advantage for this over subprocess.Popen?

Comment: @PasteBT Hmmm, good question. I'm already using `subprocess.Popen` (works very fine, thank you), but I wanted to try `sysexec()` out of pure curiosity, since it's in the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look the source code:

```
def sysexec(self, *argv, **popen_opts):
    """ return stdout text from executing a system child process,
        where the 'self' path points to executable.
        The process is directly invoked and not through a system shell.
    """
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
    argv = map_as_list(str, argv)
    popen_opts['stdout'] = popen_opts['stderr'] = PIPE
    proc = Popen([str(self)] + argv, **popen_opts)
    stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
    ret = proc.wait()
    if py.builtin._isbytes(stdout):
        stdout = py.builtin._totext(stdout, sys.getdefaultencoding())
    if ret != 0:
        if py.builtin._isbytes(stderr):
            stderr = py.builtin._totext(stderr, sys.getdefaultencoding())
        raise py.process.cmdexec.Error(ret, ret, str(self),
                                       stdout, stderr,)
    return stdout
```

clearly, It use the python [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module. If you have not been used subprocess, you can click the above link to raed the docs.
In this function, It use subprocess construct a Popen object, and use the argv you pass.
Then call the `Popen.wait()`, block until the command execute finish. And return the stdout of the command.

Example:

```
local_path = py._path.local.LocalPath('/usr/bin/ls')
print(local_path.sysexec())
# out: file1\nfile2\nfile3...
print(local_path.sysexec('-l'))
# out likes "ls -l" out
```

Comment: I do get the point of what `sysexec()` is _suposed_ to do, I actually want to know what is the right syntax to invoke it.

Comment: @baldurmen same with `subprocess.Popen`, actually, It calls `Popen([str(self)] + argv, **popen_opts)`, where the `self` path points to executable.

Comment: Well, I'm used to call `subprocess.Popen` like this: `Popen(["programname", "arg1", "arg2", path], **popen_opts)`, but with this `sysexec()` spits back a `SyntaxError`

Comment: @baldurmen I update my answer to give a example. From docs: 'self' path points to executable.    So you first need construct a LocalPath object, and it's path points to executeable.